# Regex replace all matching words that do not contain a certain string

Tags: c#, regex

How can I use regex to replace matching strings that do not include a specific string?

input string

> Keepword mywordsecond mythirdword myfourthwordKeep

string to replace

> word

exclude string

> Keep

Desired out put

> Keepword mysecond mythird myfourthKeep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will there ever be more than one `word` in a word?  If there are more than one, do you want to replace all of them?  If not, this should sort you out:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\b((?:(?!Keep|word)\w)*)word((?:(?!Keep)\w)*)\b");
s1 = r.Replace(s0, "$1$2");
```

to explain:

1. First, `\b((?:(?!Keep|word)\w)*)` captures whatever text precedes the first occurrence of `word` or `Keep`.
2. The next thing it sees must be `word`,  If it sees `Keep` or the end of the string instead, the match attempt immediately fails.
3. Then `((?:(?!Keep)\w)*)\b` captures the remainder of the text in order to ensure it doesn't contain `Keep`.

When faced with a problem like this, most users' first impulse is to match (in the sense of consuming) only the part of the string they're interested in, using lookarounds to establish the context.  It's usually much easier to write the regex so that it always moves forward through the string as it matches.  You capture the parts you want to retain so you can plug them back into the result string by means of group references (`$1`, `$2`, etc.).

Given that you're using `C#`, you *could* use the lookaround approach:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"(?<!Keep\w*)word(?!\w*Keep)");
s1 = r.Replace(s0, "");
```

But please don't.  There are very few regex flavors that support unrestricted lookbehinds like .NET does, and most problems don't work so neatly as this one anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
string str = "Keepword mywordsecond mythirdword myfourthwordKeep";
str = Regex.Replace(str, "(?<!Keep)word", "");
```

And I'm going to link you to a one of good Regular Expressions Cheat sheet [here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet)

Answer (score 0):

This works in notepad++:

```
(?<!Keep)word(?!Keep)
```

It uses "[look ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)".

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative look-behind assertion if you want to remove all "word" that are not proceeded by "Keep":

```
String input = "Keepword mywordsecond mythirdword myfourthwordKeep";
String pattern = "(?<!Keep)word";

String output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "");
```

Comment: I've tried both your solution and hatcyl's but the strings containing the "keep" word still get replaced?

Comment: @matinau I've tried this regex and I see it matches the desired output you listed in the question: `Keepword mysecond mythird myfourthKeep`. Is this not correct then?

Comment: This is my actual code, i did forget to include the replacement string in my original question

    string filecontents = File.ReadAllText(file);
    string pattern = @"(?<!" + tbxExclude.Text + ")" + OldText;
    filecontents = Regex.Replace(filecontents, pattern, NewText);

Comment: @matinau The code above provides the output you needed. I'm not sure how else I can help you.

Comment: @matinau, please edit your question and add your code to it.  We can't read it in a comment like that.